# Console says element is "null"

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

I've started to create some kind of image slider but right at the beggining i've reached a problem

Console says that my img1 and others are "null"..

Where's my mistake ?

```
let img1 = document.querySelector('.images_first active');
let img2 = document.querySelector(".images_second");
let img3 = document.querySelector(".images_third");

const fw = document.querySelector(".test-button_forward");
const back = document.querySelector(".test-button_backwards");

let clicks = 0;
console.log(img1);


fw.addEventListener('click', function()
 {
  img1.classList.remove('active');
  img2.classlist.add("active");

  clicks++;

});
```

[Full version is here](https://jsfiddle.net/fdevd7n1/5/)

Comment: They probably don't exist yet.

Comment: It should be `.images_first.active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. `.images_first active` would select an element with **tag name** `active` that is a **descendant** of an element with class `images_first`. I.e. it would find the inner element in this example:

```
<div class="images_first">
  <active></active>
</div>
```

---

However, what you actually seem to want is to find the element that has both classes, `images_first` and `active`. This is written as

```
.images_first.active
```

[Learn more about CSS selectors on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors).

---

Related: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196)

Comment: Thank you,but right now it says that img2 is not defined.I mean when you click forward it can't add a class into this element because it's "undefined"

Comment: @Matt: No, the errors says that it cannot access property `add` on `undefined`. That's because you have a typo in `img2.classlist`. The `l` of `list` should be capitalized: `img2.classList`, just like in the previous line. `img2` itself is defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
let img1 = document.querySelector('.images_first.active');
```